# Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. Prove that $A\cup B = (A-B)\cup (B-A)\cup (A\cap B)$

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, solution-verification

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. Prove that $A\cup B = (A-B)\cup (B-A)\cup (A\cap B)$.

My proof: To prove $A\cup B \subseteq (A-B)\cup(B-A)\cup(A\cap B)$ we let $x\in A\cup B$.
This means $x\in A$ or $x\in B$. Without loss of generality, assume $x\in A$ so we must have that $x\in B$, or $x\notin B$.

Case $1$: Assume $x\in B$. This means since $x\in A$, and $x\in B$, then $x\in A\cap B$.

Case $2$: Assume $x\notin B$. This means since $x\in A$ and $x\notin B$, then $x\in A-B$.

So we have $A\cup B\subseteq (A-B)\cup(B-A)\cup(A\cap B)$.

Now to prove $(A-B)\cup(B-A)\cup(A\cap B) \subseteq A\cup B$, we let $y\in (A-B)\cup(B-A)\cup(A\cap B)$. This means $y\in (A-B)$, or $y\in (B-A)$, or $y\in (A\cap B)$.

Case $1$: Let $y\in (A-B)$. This means $y\in A$ and $y\notin B$.

From here I'm not sure how to get $A\cup B$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $A \subseteq A \cup B, y \in A \Rightarrow y \in A \cup B$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $y \in A$, this guarantees that $y \in A \cup B$ because $y$ satisfies at least one "parameter" of the union.

By the union definition, if $x \in A \cup B$, then $x$ is an element of *at least one* set, $A$ or $B$.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is a proof based on the properties of the set operations:
\begin{align*}
(A - B)\cup (A\cap B) = (A\cap B^{c})\cup(A\cap B) = A\cap(B\cup B^{c}) = A
\end{align*}

Consequently, one has that
\begin{align*}
(A - B)\cup(B-A)\cup(A\cap B) = A\cup(B - A) = A\cup(B\cap A^{c}) = (A\cup B)\cap(A\cup A^{c}) = A\cup B
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps.